# CONTRACT DEPLOYMENT

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, testnets

I am trying to deploy a contract on ETH Testnet and have been unable to get test ETher. Can anyone assist me on how to get test Ether?
I've tried **Goerli facucet** and **Metamask Faucet,** all to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Without more info it's hard to tell what problem you're facing, but in general it might be worthwhile to try the Rinkeby testnet instead of Goerli. Here's the faucet for Rinkeby: https://faucet.rinkeby.io/

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems getting Ether for Testnets because it was taking time and even by posting my wallet address to social media , i was receiving nothing. At the end, the simplest way i found, was using chainlink website for `Kovan` network. It was straight forward and fast without posts on Twitter or Facebook.. and i even received LINK :D

https://faucets.chain.link/kovan